# Why do I need to disable=SC2031

Tags: bash, subshell, shellcheck

Can you tell me, why I have to `# shellcheck disable=SC2030` in the following script?

```
get_names_and_hosts(){

  unset LOCAL_HOSTS
  declare -a LOCAL_HOSTS

  unset LOCAL_NAMES
  declare -a LOCAL_NAMES

  multipass list --format json | jq -r '.list[] | [ .name, .ipv4[0] ] | @tsv' |
  while IFS=$'\t' read -r name ipaddress; do
      # shellcheck disable=SC2030
      LOCAL_NAMES+=("$name")
      # shellcheck disable=SC2030
      LOCAL_HOSTS+=($ipaddress)
  done

  # shellcheck disable=SC2031
  reply=("${LOCAL_NAMES[@]}" "${LOCAL_HOSTS[@]}")
  echo "${reply[@]}"
}
```

declare as `declare -gx` gives the same warning?

Comment: You noticed those are commented lines?

Comment: Yes, what do you mean - I am suppressing the warning?

Comment: Yes, the script is working - I was just wondering why shellcheck is complaining

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because the previous line ends with `|`, the `while ... do ... done` loop is part of the pipeline: you are *piping into a loop*.

Because of this, the loop may be executed in a subshell, and so any changes to the variables `LOCAL_NAMES` and `LOCAL_HOSTS` might be lost depending on which shell you are actually using to run this script: it will work with `ksh`, `zsh` and also with `bash` if you have `bash`'s `lastpipe` option set.

With other shells, or with `bash`'s factory-default settings, it will fail.

Was the explanation on https://www.shellcheck.net/wiki/SC2031 not clear for you?